# change the background color of customize tableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to change my cell's background color

I see other question but they are not correspond my situation

I want to do a notification tableView

for example,If user have read cell, the cell's background color will change to white

If not, the color is yellow

At beginning

I set color in

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

   if(read[[indexPath row]])
     [cell.backView setBckgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor];
   else
     [cell.backView setBckgroundColor:[UIColor redColor];
}
```

It works, and then i want to change color in

```
tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
   read[[indexPath row]] = yes;
   [cell.backView setBckgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor];
   cell.name.text = @"test";
}
```

it works too

BUT if i selection other cell, it change to orignial color

It seems it only can change ONE cell's color at same time

No matter I use

```
cell.backgroundColor
cell.contentView.backgroundColor
cell.backView
```

it get the same result,can anyone help me

---

edit 4/20   20:13

I set read in

```
tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

sorry for misdirection,i update code

and after i selection other cell, i don't call [tableView reload]

so i don't think this is the reason

By the way, everything(e.g label) can change but background color

and if i select cell , it jump to other screen by navigation

---

Ans

conclusion first

```
tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: is well
```

and

```
tableView: willDisplayCell: is well too
```

both of them can change background color

but they execute when need to draw new cell or reload tableView

I still confuse why I can change label in didselectionRowAtIndexPath
but i can't change color

Answer (score 2):

Change color using `tableView: willDisplayCell:` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (...){ //do your stuff.
        [cell.backView setBckgroundColor:[UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        [cell.backView setBckgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set your variable "read" to YES in

`tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath`

and I guess you use only one variable to record the states just because you simplified it for posting here, otherwise you might want to record the state of each cell with separate variables.

Comment: i do that but it doesn't work,i edit code again thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the "read" property of the object at the index of your cell.

```
tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
   [cell.backView setBckgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor];
   currentObjectForThisCell.read = YES;
}
```

then:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
   if(currentObjectForThisCell.read)
     [cell.backView setBckgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor];
   else
     [cell.backView setBckgroundColor:[UIColor redColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your edited code, when you select the cell, you set the read flag to YES and change the color to white, that's fine, but in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you set cells with the read flag YES to red, and NO to white, which is opposite to the behaviour in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the Selected cell in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

//set read property for the seleted index

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you called reloadData for the tableView 
Set read property in the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" and reload the tableView

Comment: I set read property in didSelectRowAtIndexPath but I don't reload the tableView