# Change background colour of Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to change the background colour of a table cell if a NEW item has been inserted. I am able to change the background colour for all the cells but however i just one the newly added ones to change colour.

Is there any way this can be done?

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(OutgoingHolder*)expense {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    Outgoing *outgoing = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    //[newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];

    // Save the context.

    outgoing.costDescription = expense.costDescription;
    outgoing.amount = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:expense.amount];
    outgoing.date = expense.date;
    outgoing.category = expense.category;


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    //CHANGES HERE
    self.addedNewRow=0;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}





#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

-(NSString*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    return[sectionInfo name];


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (_total > 0.0 ) {
        //UPDATE 1:
        NSLog(@"%@",[@"Total : " stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", self.total]]);
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][indexPath.section];
        if ([sectionInfo numberOfObjects]-1  == indexPath.row  && self.addedNewRow!=-1) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }
    }


    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Outgoing *outgoing = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = outgoing.costDescription;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[outgoing.amount floatValue]];

}
```

Comment: is there anything you tried, you can show us?

Comment: you can change the background colour for each individual cell, you are not limited to do it for _all_ only.

Comment: Post your code, which you have tried,

Comment: How are you adding new cell? Can u post that code also?

Comment: @ViralSavaj Please see the edited question for the code

Comment: Is it that, new entity always inserted at last position?

Comment: @ViralSavaj What does that mean?

Comment: @john - where are you reloading your table when a new object is inserted?

Comment: As you are adding new entity through `insertNewObject` method, is this method enter new entity always at last position, or it can be inserted in between also??

Answer (score 1):

You can get the newly added cell with the following way, only if the new cell always added at last position.

Just define flag variable in your `.h` file like

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int addedNewRow;
```

Now in your `.m` file initialise that `addedNewRow` with `-1` like,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.addedNewRow=-1;
    //other stuff
}
```

Replace below two method which has little bit enhancement from your code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    //UPDATE 1:
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][indexPath.section];
    if ([sectionInfo numberOfObjects]-1  == indexPath.row  && self.addedNewRow!=-1) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)insertNewElement:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    Outgoing *outgoing = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    //[newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];

    // Save the context.

    outgoing.costDescription = expense.costDescription;
    outgoing.amount = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:expense.amount];
    outgoing.date = expense.date;
    outgoing.category = expense.category;


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    //CHANGES HERE
    self.addedNewRow=0;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope this helps you !!

Comment: I receive an error on id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];  on the [section]

Comment: @John, fine 'UPDATE 1:' update from edited answer and replace next line

Comment: This is still highlighting all the cells. When the application is loaded the background colour doesn't appear but when i add a new item all cells highlight

Comment: I also have an if statement to check if a value is greater than another value. IF that value is greater only then do i want the new cell to be highlighted. The rest will stay the same.

Comment: What im trying to do is only highlight the new cells added if the total I have is greater than 0. The new highlighted one should stay highlighted if i add a new one, if the value is still greater. But if the value is not greater then the background will be default

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer:

numberOfRowsInSection method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [dataArray count];
}
```

Within cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
if(indexPath.row == dataArray.count-1){
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

Edit 1:

`dataArray` is the array used to populate table rows, is the one you use to check the total number of elements in array to load in table within `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Comment: What is dataArray being used for?

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    if(indexPath.row == dataArray.count-1){
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
        return cell;
}

Comment: dataArray is the array used to feed table row.

Comment: Im fairly new with table views, I receive an error on dataArray, Im not entirely sure what my array is. Where would it be declared?

Comment: Question updated! It is always better to post your code in question.

Comment: Hi, i have posted the code above, could you please see where i am going wrong?

Comment: @John, you are alway tried to change color of last row so instead of this tried my solution with help of taking one more parameter as lastselectedIndex.

Comment: @john - what happens when you do this - `if(indexPath.row == [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]-1)` ?

Comment: I just tried that but the cell colour still does not change

Answer (score 0):

You can applied validation in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for newly added cell.

in .h file declare one variable.

```
Outgoing *lastOutgoing;
```

As initial `lastOutgoing = nil` in `viewDidLoad` method. once new object is add. keep reference of that object in `lastOutgoing`. here are the `insertNewObject` modified method.

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(OutgoingHolder*)expense {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    Outgoing *outgoing = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    //[newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];

    // Save the context.

    outgoing.costDescription = expense.costDescription;
    outgoing.amount = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:expense.amount];
    outgoing.date = expense.date;
    outgoing.category = expense.category;


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

  lastOutgoing = outgoing;
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In configureCell method

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Outgoing *outgoing = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = outgoing.costDescription;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[outgoing.amount floatValue]];

   if([lastOutgoing isEqual:outgoing]){
      cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
   }

}
```

Hope this help you..

Comment: Initially, without adding a new cell, it will change the color of last cell.

Comment: @viral - you don't want  last cell color to be different when the table loads for the first time, only change color when new cell/row added?

Comment: @the_UB, just applied one more validation for initial data load.

Comment: @None Im having trouble finding the array that is being fed into the method. Yours is dataArray but i dont know what my one is

Comment: @John, you don't  need that code. just removed that.

Comment: @None This did not work for me, the cell colour did not change

Comment: @John, have you implemented didSelectRowAtIndexPath as i shown in post ?

Comment: @None Please see the edited question for the code which has all my code

Comment: @John, are you adding new section each time once insertNewObject called ?

Comment: @John, each section has only single row ?

Comment: @John, i have updated my code according to your requirement. if still you have any problem then content me

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor blueColor];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work, with only newly added cell?

Answer (score 0):

Store the newly inserted `indexPath`, and check for that indexPath in the `willDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method, and change the cell's contentView's background color.

Answer (score 0):

Change color using `tableView: willDisplayCell:` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (...){ //do your stuff.
        [cell.backView setBckgroundColor:[UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        [cell.backView setBckgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

[change the background color of customize tableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744718/change-the-background-color-of-customize-tableviewcell/29744829#29744829)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    if (indexPath.row == dataArray.count-1)
    {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:123/255.0 green:234.0/255.0 blue:255/225.0 alpha:1.0]];
    }
}
```